# 13.10 - Blank terminal prompt (no working directory displayed)

Tags: 13.10, gnome-terminal

Upon opening a new terminal window, I'm getting a blank prompt with a flashing cursor.

[New terminal window / blank promp (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwbbE.png)

This just started happening the last couple days and I can't seem to find a solution. Prior to this, I modified .bashrc to shorten the working directory. I also included some RVM scripts for configuring a Rails environment.

```
#   01/15/14 
#   Hide working directory on prompt
    export PS1="\W: "

#   RVM Scripts
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

I can get a working prompt by entering `ctrl+c`, however, this then ignores the .bashrc snippet for shortening the working directory.

[Working prompt (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfDWr.png)

Rebooting does not solve this.

Comment: I was able to get everything working by simply removing the '.profile' line in .bashrc and restarting the terminal. Thank you @falconer for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile"
```

will source your `.profile` file in your `.bashrc`

On my Ubuntu install and I think on all Ubuntu/Debian install `.profile` contains this:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

That means your `.profile`also sources your `.bashrc`. So you get into a nice infinite loop.

Don't source `.profile` from `.bashrc`, it is unnecessary. Remove that line.

(What I don't understand how can you login at all?)

Answer (score 0):

Are you shure, that you have sh/bash access? Can you please post

```
# cat /etc/passwd
```